# Are Xbox 360 hard drives always labeled when larger than 20 GB?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm trying to buy a used 120 GB hard drive online. Many of the listings have photographs of HDDs which don't have a size etched on the top, but still claim to be 120 GB. Is that possible? Does anybody own an unlabeled 120 GB drive?

Edit: We can generally assume these have not been modified, imagine a semi-literate ebay seller.

Answer (score 2):

You can install 3rd party hard drives just fine on the Xbox 360. If the above user did that it would be unlabeled.

So **YES!** it is completly possible tor a 120 GB hard drive to be unlabeled. If you want to do this your self, it is a very easy process. More information on that can be found [here.](http://www.pcworld.com/article/150970/upgrade_your_xbox_360s_hard_drive_on_the_cheap.html)

Comment: Good point! In my particular case, the seller replied to my inquiry with "there is a code on the back i searched it and it said 120 gb harddrive", so I'm guessing this one is unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definite answer, but this seller eventually realized he was mistaken about the capacity. If you're looking to buy a used HDD, you should be extremely skeptical if there's no label on the metallic strip and it's advertised to be more than 20 GB.